# how to slice a dataframe and reassemble it into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get a dataframe like this:

```
A   YEAR2000    B   YEAR2001    C   YEAR2002
a      1        b     3         a      7
b      3        c     5         e      6
c      6        d     2         f      3
                e     1         g      0
```

Slice every two columns and then reorganize to form a new dataframe, as follows:

```
type    YEAR2000    YEAR2001    YEAR2002
a         1                         7
b         3            3    
c         6            5    
d                      2    
e                      1            6
f                                   3
g                                   0
```

I have tried `pd.concat()` but somethings wrong happened! Thank you.

Comment: You should provide your code so as to show what you tried so far.

Comment: Set the index before `concat`, then it will align with `axis=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using merge twice will achieve it.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 6]],columns=['letter', 'number'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['b', 3], ['c', 5], ['d', 2], ['e', 1]],columns=['letter', 'number'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 7], ['e', 6], ['f', 3], ['g', 0]],columns=['letter', 'number'])
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='letter'), df3, how='outer', on='letter')
```

for cleaner look:

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='letter').merge(df3, how='outer', on='letter')
```

if you have mutiple dataframe, put them into a list and use comprehension with reduce.

```py
from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
reduce(lambda left, right: left.merge(right, how='outer', on='letter'), dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!but if the numbers of dataframe is more than 10,100 or bigger,what should i do?

Comment: @Fighting You are welcome :)  If you accept the answer, you can click the accept button on the left (the tick symbol ✓).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do with `groupby`with `axis=1` then `concat`

```
l=[y.set_index(y.columns[0]).dropna() for x , y in df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//2,axis=1)]
pd.concat(l,axis=1,sort=True)
Out[858]: 
   YEAR2000  YEAR2001  YEAR2002
a       1.0       NaN       7.0
b       3.0       3.0       NaN
c       6.0       5.0       NaN
d       NaN       2.0       NaN
e       NaN       1.0       6.0
f       NaN       NaN       3.0
g       NaN       NaN       0.0
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I have a try,it functions well

Answer (score 0):

My code as follows:

```
dataframe_list = []
for i in range(0,origin_df.columns.size):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        dataframe_list.append(origin_df.iloc[:,[i,i + 1]])
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
new_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframe_list,axis = 0)
new_dataframe
```

Comment: If you want the approach using `pd.concat`, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have more than 6 columns:

```
num_cols = len(df.columns)
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,i:i+2].dropna()
             .set_index(df.columns[i])
                   for i in range(0,len(df.columns),2)],
          axis=1,
          sort=True
          )
```

Output:

```
    YEAR2000    YEAR2001    YEAR2002
a   1.0         NaN         7.0
b   3.0         3.0         NaN
c   6.0         5.0         NaN
d   NaN         2.0         NaN
e   NaN         1.0         6.0
f   NaN         NaN         3.0
g   NaN         NaN         0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple solution is using `pd.concat`. Just need `set_index` to columns `A`, `B`, `C`... of these sub-dataframes before `pd.concat`. For `df` with huge numbers of  columns with unknown names, it easily accomplishes by using `iter` and `zip` as follows:

```
it = iter(df)
cols_list = list(map(list, zip(it, it)))

Out[1854]: [['A', 'YEAR2000'], ['B', 'YEAR2001'], ['C', 'YEAR2002']]
```

Next, using listcomp creat list of sub-dataframes with `set_index` from `cols_list` and `pd.concat`

```
dfs = [df[cols].set_index(cols[0]) for cols in cols_list]
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).dropna(axis=0, how='all')

Out[1868]:
   YEAR2000  YEAR2001  YEAR2002
a       1.0       NaN       7.0
b       3.0       3.0       NaN
c       6.0       5.0       NaN
d       NaN       2.0       NaN
e       NaN       1.0       6.0
f       NaN       NaN       3.0
g       NaN       NaN       0.0
```

Comment: thank you for your help! i am new for pandas, so i am keeping learning!